# Angular 2 Service Singleton Scoping Problems

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 2 service that I can't seem to get working correctly.  For some reason the scoping on *this* isn't what I would expect it to be.  I'm using fat arrows, which should keep things scoped correctly but I'm not sure where the wheels are falling off.

**The Service**

```
declare const Trello: any;

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class TrelloService {
    key: string = 'test';
    token: string = 'test';
    boards: any = [];

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('Initializing TrelloService.  You should only see me once.');
    }

    getOpenBoards(): Promise<void> {
        // 'this' is null here.  No scope at all???
        const url = `https://api.trello.com/1/member/me/boards?key=${this.key}&token=${this.token}`;
        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then((response: Response) => {
                debugger;
                this.boards = response.json();
            });
    }
}
```

The component below calls `getOpenBoards` on the service.  When it does, `this` is null.  This screams "crazy javascript scoping problem", but I have no idea what to do with it.  Do I need to `bind` everywhere?  If so, how would I even do that from the component?

**The Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CatchflyService } from '../../services/catchfly.service';
import { TrelloService } from '../../services/trello.service';

declare var Trello: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'step-fetch-data',
    templateUrl: './fetchData.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./fetchData.component.scss']
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
    showError: boolean = false;

    constructor(private trelloService: TrelloService,
                private catchflyService: CatchflyService,
                private router: Router) {

        this.catchflyService.getProjects()
            .then(this.trelloService.getOpenBoards)
            .then(this.trelloService.getAllLists)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('finished getting projects, boards, and lists');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                console.log('service rejected');
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a final note that might be of relevance to you. Not sure if you get a notification for the edit, so hopefully this comment will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  Yeah, they're serialized by design.  I hope that others that come across this question find your thorough answer as useful as i have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're calling the `then` function like you do:

```
this.catchflyService.getProjects()
  .then(this.trelloService.getOpenBoards)
  .then(this.trelloService.getAllLists)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('finished getting projects, boards, and lists');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('service rejected');
});
```

You are passing the `getOpenBoards` function as a reference, which makes it lose it's binding to the object it's on. You can do one of two things:

**1: Call the function directly in a handler:**

```
this.catchflyService.getProjects()
  .then(i => this.trelloService.getOpenBoards())
  .then(i => this.trelloService.getAllLists())
  .then(() => {
    console.log('finished getting projects, boards, and lists');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('service rejected');
});
```

**2: Bind the function when passing it in:**

```
this.catchflyService.getProjects()
  .then(this.trelloService.getOpenBoards.bind(this.trelloService))
  .then(this.trelloService.getAllLists.bind(this.trelloService))
  .then(() => {
    console.log('finished getting projects, boards, and lists');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('service rejected');
});
```

**EDIT**

One final note. What I assume you're doing here is calling three async methods that have no dependencies (as there are no parameters to the functions passed to `then`). Because of the way you're chaining the `then` functions they are called in sequence. If there are no dependencies between the three calls, you can futher optimise your code by calling them in parallel:

```
var p1 = this.catchflyService.getProjects();
var p2 = this.trelloService.getOpenBoards();
var p3 = this.trelloService.getAllLists();

Promise.all([p1,p2,p3])
  .then(() => {
    console.log('finished getting projects, boards, and lists');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('service rejected');
});
```

Comment: From TS perspective 1 is better, because `bind` is still type unsafe.

Comment: I concur, always use method 1 myself, but felt like it should be mentioned if only to futher illustrate why the code in de question doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting then .then() calls into functions.

```
export class FetchDataComponent
{
    showError: boolean = false;

    constructor(private trelloService: TrelloService,
                private catchflyService: CatchflyService,
                private router: Router)
    {

        this.catchflyService.getProjects()
            .then(()=>
            {
                this.trelloService.getOpenBoards()
            })
            .then(()=>
            {
                this.trelloService.getAllLists()
            })
            .then(() =>
            {
                console.log('finished getting projects, boards, and lists');
            })
            .catch((err) =>
            {
                console.log(err);
                console.log('service rejected');
            });
    }
}
```